# Using ' in string.xml file

Tags: android, string, apostrophe

I have given app_name as below :

```
 <string name="app_name">My \'App</string>
```

to use apostrophe I used \ in it.

But, still it giving me below error:

```
Error:(2) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in My 'App)
```

So, I removed **'** from the app_name and write it as simply My App.
But, still it giving me same error, I have restarted android studio, cleaned project and even restarted my system but,still getting same error.

Comment: use &apos; where you want to add it and remove slash

Comment: take a look for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15705691/3005903

Comment: @VivekMishra Now It giving me same error two times.

Comment: @AhmadAlkhateeb I have already tried both the way.. using \ and ".." to include ' in string.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein It gives me same error if I am using app_name as My App. Without including ' (apostrophe), but still Why it giving me same error ? I have Rebuild project and restarted Android Studio.

Comment: @All, Its working.. actually I have taken it two times.. Thank you All for youe efforts..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your line

```
 <string name="app_name">My \'App</string>
```

with

```
 <string name="app_name">My &#39;App</string>
```