# Execution Failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error from `build-tools\23.0.2\ (Aapt.exe)`

> finished with non zero exit value 1.

I am using `Android Studio Version 1.4.1`

I am using the `API level 23` with the updated build tools, and my log cat is often meaning out the `string.xml` where I created my strings to refer it for the list view.

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources,
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :mylibrary:generateDebugSources,
>   :mylibrary:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,
>   :mylibrary:compileDebugSources,
>   :mylibrary:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources AGPBI: { "kind":"error","text":"Apostrophe
>   not preceded by \  ( in ithin the lifecycle callback methods, you can
>   declare how your activity behaves when the user leaves and re-enters
>   the activity. For example, if you\u0027re building a streaming video
>   player, you might pause the video and terminate the network connection
>   when the user switches to another app. When the user returns, you can
>   reconnect to the network and allow the user to resume the video from
>   the same spot. )", "sources":[
>   {"file":"C:\Users\PreciseT3\AndroidStudioProjects\ListviewApp1\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml","position":
>   { "startLine":1}}],"original":""}
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Users\PreciseT3\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe''
>   >     finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 12.649 secs

Comment: add full logs of gradle console

Comment: Mr.Dhawal can you please explain your solution such as briefly since i am new to android and Gradle too....

Comment: in android studio at bottom right corner there is Gradle console. when you try to build & clean app some logs are generate. get that logs and post its in question

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Dhawal..

Comment: My following lines are found at Gradle console.....try to help me out ...

Comment: suggest to read once Android Studio Tips and Tricks http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html

Comment: where that i can not see that ad all in question

Comment: Hai mr.dhawal done......>>>>>guide me out with pleasure.....

Comment: its issue of single quote in string.xml file have used single quote in string.xml file if yse then check answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/5657047/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15705647/1168654

Comment: Thanks for your Solution......Actually i found it early....By the way thanks for your valuable reply towards my confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `string.xml`

find all occurrences of single-quote (`'`) or apostrophe and add a back-slash escape character (`\`) before each occurrence.

XML cannot deal with (`'`)

**Basically, replace all `'` with `\'`**

Comment: Thanks for your Solution......Actually i found it early....By the way thanks for your valuable reply towards my confusion....

Answer (score 0):

Compare your gradle file I hope this work

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.tranetech.laundry"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```