# Not possible to run/bulid apk in android studio. error : Apostrophe not preceded by

Tags: android, android-studio

Not possible to run/bulid apk in android studio.

Android studio :3.1.3

First comes this **error 1** :

```
> Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Transfer from one wallet to another
> within Message{kind=ERROR, text=Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in
> Transfer from one wallet to another within,
> sources=[..\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\res\values\values.xml:1152:5-56],
> original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

Removed all Apostrophe text from strings.still bug exist, so then commented all String file. then comes this error

**Error 2**

```
>     text=Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Transfer from one wallet to another within,
> sources=[C:\....\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\3c34a606a8ff20177b51bf6cae208059\res\values\values.xml:385:5-78]
>     
>     Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with
> non-zero exit value 1
```

screenshot 
[image]

Tried all solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705647/apostrophe-not-preceded-by) still bug exist. 
Invalidate/Restart also done.anyway to solve this bug ?

Comment: Have you tried Build > Clean Project ?

Comment: @Bubu clean project, rebuild project ,  Invalidate/Restart  are done. but result is same